# jquery $(this).data not working properly in dataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a table in html and I use [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) for my tables I show a brief info of my users data in this table, and I have a button in the last column

```
<tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1">1</td>
      <td>یوسف توکلی</td> 
      <td>۲۹۶۰۰۰۰۴</td> 
      <td>۹۸۷۶۵۴۳۲۱</td> 
      <td>مهندسی فناوری اطلاعات</td> 
      <td>دیپلم</td> 
      <td>کاربر</td> 
      <td><button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-user="192" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg1" class="detailes btn btn-default btn-md m-t-10">جزئیات</button></td>
  </tr>
```

this button show a modal contain details of that user. I use AJAX for getting data from server using `data-user` as a key.

This ajax request work fine for top 10 user but for others request not sent and when we click on button in model showed last request data

this is my ajax request

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".detailes").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var user_id = $(this).attr('data-user');
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>" + "admin/user_detailes",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {view_id: user_id},
                success: function(res) {
                    // res = JSON.stringify(res);
                    console.log(res);
                    if (res){
                      $("#myLargeModalLabel").html(' <i class=" ti-angle-double-left"></i> ' + res.firstname + " " + res.lastname  );
                      $(".code").html(res.code);
                      $(".ncode").html(res.ncode);
                      $(".firstname").html(res.firstname + " " + res.lastname);
                      $(".jplace").html(res.jplace);
                      $(".phone").html(res.phone);
                      $(".mobile").html(res.mobile);
                      $(".mail").html(res.mail);
                      $(".website").html(res.website);
                      $(".gender").html(res.gender);
                      $(".marriage").html(res.marriage);
                      $(".field").html(res.field);
                      $(".degree").html(res.degree);
                      $(".father").html(res.father);
                      $(".last_click_time").html(res.last_click_time);
                      $(".birthday").html(res.birthday);
                      $(".job").html(res.job);
                      $(".username").html(res.username);
                      $(".level").html(res.level);
                      $(".birthdate").html(res.birthdate);
                      $(".reg_time").html(res.reg_time);
                    }
                  }
            })
        })
    });
```

Any one knows what happens?

Comment: If you're using datatables, you should probably use the datatable's data store rather than rely on data- attributes.  You can retrieve the row's underlying data which should include your user id.

Comment: @freedomn-m I couldnt find something like `data-store` can you explain more please

Comment: https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()

Comment: It's because of the way you're binding the button click event. Use the API properly and bind it in [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback)